# WebRTC Native Android Switch audio source?

Tags: android, webrtc, native

I am using webrtc native for android and while using bluetooth, the webrtc lib doesn't select the bluetooth headset as default mic, so how to switch audio source that is microphone, like in the whatsapp,
currently i am creating audio source like as,

```
        AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());

        AudioTrack localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSv1", audioSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to change webrtc audioTrack, only AudioManager settings. To use bluetooth headset:

```
private val audioManager: AudioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager    
if (!audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn) {
                        audioManager.startBluetoothSco()
                    }
audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn = true
```

To switch back to phone speaker:

```
audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn = false
audioManager.stopBluetoothSco()
```

And I don`t properly remember, but if code above doesn`t work, change also audiomanager mode like this:

```
audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
```